# Cordova iOS Splash Screen stays waaay too long

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

So, I'm using a "splash screen" for my Cordova iOS application. I'm actually using the "LaunchStoryBoard" image. My issue is that it seems to stay for a very long time before finally getting dismissed. A solid 3 seconds (as in 1 mississippi, etc.).

I've looked around on stackoverflow, but a lot of responses seem to be for the Ionic framework / Android. I'm not using that. Just straight Cordova with iOS.

Here is my config.xml:

```
 <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
    </platform>
```

And in my app's "General Settings" I have "Launch Screen File" set to CDVLaunchScreen.

Again, it works fine, just stays too long. It would be great to shave even 1 second off of it.

Also, if you have any custom javascript tips/help, please let me know what file it should be put into (e.g., index.js).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the entire config.xml? Any other plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go about it.

1. You can try using cordova [splash screen plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) and make use of `SplashScreenDelay` preference to set delay of your choice.
2. You can use the splash screen plugin, set the `AutoHideSplashScreen` preference to `false` and then you can use this code in onload of your index page to hide the splashscreen:

   > navigator.splashscreen.hide();